# React - How to set my invite attribute to false of id 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, class

My goal is to change the class of a button based on the status of the invite attribute.
I wanted to create a function so that when you click on the button, it changes the status of invite.

Here is my code :

```js
export default class Team extends Component {

constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            datas: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5e/62/f1/5e62f1a8adecdeb028d6a78e6e755127.jpg',
                    name: 'OLAKERTAL',
                    role: 'Jungle, Mid',
                    rang: 'https://img2.gratispng.com/20180627/etk/kisspng-league-of-legends-world-of-warcraft-riot-games-gol-bronze-5b33297713b100.6997811915300796070807.jpg',
                    invite: true,
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5e/62/f1/5e62f1a8adecdeb028d6a78e6e755127.jpg',
                    name: 'Ali',
                    role: 'Jungle, Mid',
                    rang: 'https://img2.gratispng.com/20180627/etk/kisspng-league-of-legends-world-of-warcraft-riot-games-gol-bronze-5b33297713b100.6997811915300796070807.jpg',
                    invite: true,
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5e/62/f1/5e62f1a8adecdeb028d6a78e6e755127.jpg',
                    name: 'Saad',
                    role: 'Jungle, Mid',
                    rang: 'https://img2.gratispng.com/20180627/etk/kisspng-league-of-legends-world-of-warcraft-riot-games-gol-bronze-5b33297713b100.6997811915300796070807.jpg',
                    invite: true,
                },
            ]
        }
    }

    renderTableData() {
        return this.state.datas.map((data, index) => {
            let { image, name, role, rang, invite } = data 
            function bouton() {
                invite === true ? invite = false : invite = true
                console.log(55)
            }

            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <div>
                        <img alt="img" src={image} />
                        <div>
                            <h4>{name}</h4>
                            <div>Roles : {role}</div>
                        </div>
                        <img alt="img-2" onClick={this.props.image} src={rang} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button className={invite === false ? "bouton-white" : "" } onClick={bouton}>Invite</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
}
```

But he doesn't want to change the status of invite.
I put a cosole.log () to see if it fits my function and it puts my console.log well But the change of status does not change ...

Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Need some clarity here. You want to toggle the `invite` flag based on the respective button click ?

Comment: Yes, when clicked, I want to change the invite value to false if it was already true and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bouton" function just changes the local variable "invite" and has nothing to do with your original data object.

You need to store the "datas" array in state and in button onClick put a function that receives the index of the data in datas array and change the invite inside of the state by using that (with setState function of course).